# diff two multilines bash variables to list what lines aren't in the other

Tags: bash, variable, diff

I've created a `bash` script that

1. Lists the document IDs I've put in an *Elastic* index, in `$liste_ids_lines`:

   ```
    a004-événements-examen_individus_localisés_ou_non
    a020-les_points-leurs_indicateurs-usage_dans_postgis
    a022-les_lignes-leurs_indicateurs-usage_dans_postgis
    a024-les_vecteurs-leurs_indicateurs-usage_dans_postgis
    a030-topologie_avec_PostGIS
    a031-topologie_relations_spatiales-voisinages_arrangements
    a032-topologie_espace_plan_homogène_isotrope-synthese_objets_et_dispersion
    a033-topologie_distribution_spatiale-et-pondération_par_la_distance
    a037-topologie-indicateurs_arrangement_spatial_par_classe-objets_zonaux
    a038-topologie_les_indicateurs_arrangement_spatial_par_région-objets-zonaux
    a039-topologie_les_indices_de_texture_et_de_structure
    a050-auto-correlation_spatiale
    a060-cartographie
    a061-mise_en_évidence_valeurs_significatives-correction_des_taux
    a062-interpolations-et-surfaces_de_tendance
    a091-modelisation-la_recherche_de_modele
    a092-modélisation_analyses-locales-et-globales
    a093-voisinages_et_autocorrelation_spatiale
    a094-inferences_generalisations_correlations
    a095-evolution_dans_le_temps-le_mouvement
    a096-evolution_dans_le_temps-processus
    a151-le_modele_de_paysage
    a406-topologie-passer_de_la_geometrie_a_la_topologie-postgis
    a410-topologie-les_operations
    a480-topologie-parcours_de_reseau-pgRouting
    a500-les_protocoles_des-services_géographiques-wms_wfs_etc
    a600-postgis-installation_et_configuration
    a621-postgis-chargement_de_donnees
    a623-postgis_ses_types_de_données
    a631-postgis-intersections_et_reunions
    a700-géocodage_adresses_coordonnées
   ```
2. Lists my `pdf` files in their folders and retaisn their name without their directory or extension, in `$liste_fichiers`:

   ```
   a000-les_usages_de_la_cartographie
   a004-événements-examen_individus_localisés_ou_non
   a020-les_points-leurs_indicateurs-usage_dans_postgis
   a022-les_lignes-leurs_indicateurs-usage_dans_postgis
   a024-les_vecteurs-leurs_indicateurs-usage_dans_postgis
   a030-topologie_avec_PostGIS
   a031-topologie_relations_spatiales-voisinages_arrangements
   a032-topologie_espace_plan_homogène_isotrope-synthese_objets_et_dispersion
   a033-topologie_distribution_spatiale-et-pondération_par_la_distance
   a037-topologie-indicateurs_arrangement_spatial_par_classe-objets_zonaux
   a038-topologie_les_indicateurs_arrangement_spatial_par_région-objets-zonaux
   a039-topologie_les_indices_de_texture_et_de_structure
   a050-auto-correlation_spatiale
   a060-cartographie
   a061-mise_en_évidence_valeurs_significatives-correction_des_taux
   a062-interpolations-et-surfaces_de_tendance
   a091-modelisation-la_recherche_de_modele
   a092-modélisation_analyses-locales-et-globales
   a093-voisinages_et_autocorrelation_spatiale
   a094-inferences_generalisations_correlations
   a095-evolution_dans_le_temps-le_mouvement
   a096-evolution_dans_le_temps-processus
   a151-le_modele_de_paysage
   a201-extraction_données-et-modélisation_en_objets
   a406-topologie-passer_de_la_geometrie_a_la_topologie-postgis
   a410-topologie-les_operations
   a480-topologie-parcours_de_reseau-pgRouting
   a500-les_protocoles_des-services_géographiques-wms_wfs_etc
   a600-postgis-installation_et_configuration
   a621-postgis-chargement_de_donnees
   a623-postgis_ses_types_de_données
   a631-postgis-intersections_et_reunions
   a650-postgis-extraction_depuis_une_image_satellite
   a700-géocodage_adresses_coordonnées
   analyse_spatiale
   analyse_spatiale-a000-les-usages-de-la-cartographie
   analyse_spatiale-a022-postgis-extraction-depuis-une-image-satellite
   analyse_spatiale-a090-explicatif-modéliser-ce-qui-est-observé
   analyse_spatiale-a120-géodésie-et-projections
   analyse_spatiale-a150-le-modèle-numérique-de-terrain
   analyse_spatiale-a180-mapserver-installation-et-configuration
   analyse_spatiale-a181-mapserver-la-structure-d'un-mapfile
   analyse_spatiale-a191-grass-qgis-manipulations-générales
   ```

I would like to know what line isn't in the other list, considering these variables by their lines.

Currently, my `diff` command:

```bash
diff <( echo "$liste_ids_lines" ) <( echo "$liste_fichiers" )
```

lists (I'm reporting only a part of the command result):

```
1c1,225
< 
---
> a000-les_usages_de_la_cartographie
> a004-événements-examen_individus_localisés_ou_non
> a020-les_points-leurs_indicateurs-usage_dans_postgis
> a022-les_lignes-leurs_indicateurs-usage_dans_postgis
> a024-les_vecteurs-leurs_indicateurs-usage_dans_postgis
> a030-topologie_avec_PostGIS
> a031-topologie_relations_spatiales-voisinages_arrangements
> a032-topologie_espace_plan_homogène_isotrope-synthese_objets_et_dispersion
> a033-topologie_distribution_spatiale-et-pondération_par_la_distance
> a037-topologie-indicateurs_arrangement_spatial_par_classe-objets_zonaux
> a038-topologie_les_indicateurs_arrangement_spatial_par_région-objets-zonaux
> a039-topologie_les_indices_de_texture_et_de_structure
> a050-auto-correlation_spatiale
> a060-cartographie
> a061-mise_en_évidence_valeurs_significatives-correction_des_taux
> a062-interpolations-et-surfaces_de_tendance
> a091-modelisation-la_recherche_de_modele
> a092-modélisation_analyses-locales-et-globales
> a093-voisinages_et_autocorrelation_spatiale
> a094-inferences_generalisations_correlations
> a095-evolution_dans_le_temps-le_mouvement
> a096-evolution_dans_le_temps-processus
> a151-le_modele_de_paysage
> a201-extraction_données-et-modélisation_en_objets
> a406-topologie-passer_de_la_geometrie_a_la_topologie-postgis
> a410-topologie-les_operations
> a480-topologie-parcours_de_reseau-pgRouting
> a500-les_protocoles_des-services_géographiques-wms_wfs_etc
> a600-postgis-installation_et_configuration
> a621-postgis-chargement_de_donnees
> a623-postgis_ses_types_de_données
> a631-postgis-intersections_et_reunions
> a650-postgis-extraction_depuis_une_image_satellite
> a700-géocodage_adresses_coordonnées
> analyse_spatiale
> analyse_spatiale-a000-les-usages-de-la-cartographie
> analyse_spatiale-a022-postgis-extraction-depuis-une-image-satellite
> analyse_spatiale-a090-explicatif-modéliser-ce-qui-est-observé
> analyse_spatiale-a120-géodésie-et-projections
> analyse_spatiale-a150-le-modèle-numérique-de-terrain
> analyse_spatiale-a180-mapserver-installation-et-configuration
> analyse_spatiale-a181-mapserver-la-structure-d'un-mapfile
> analyse_spatiale-a191-grass-qgis-manipulations-générales
```

And I would like to read, instead:
either, the files that have no index:

```
a000-les_usages_de_la_cartographie
analyse_spatiale
analyse_spatiale-a000-les-usages-de-la-cartographie
analyse_spatiale-a022-postgis-extraction-depuis-une-image-satellite
analyse_spatiale-a090-explicatif-modéliser-ce-qui-est-observé
analyse_spatiale-a120-géodésie-et-projections
analyse_spatiale-a150-le-modèle-numérique-de-terrain
analyse_spatiale-a180-mapserver-installation-et-configuration
analyse_spatiale-a181-mapserver-la-structure-d'un-mapfile
analyse_spatiale-a191-grass-qgis-manipulations-générales
```

or the indices that don't have an associated file.

(I think it will require the execution of two `diff` commands, having their arguments switched)

Is it achievable by my `diff` command?
or should it be done by a special `grep` command?

Comment: Why is  the line `a004-événements-examen_individus_localisés_ou_non` which exists in both the lists appears in your `diff` output?

Comment: @davidt930 I don't understand why. The result of my diff command looks strange to me, and this is why I've opened this question: `diff`doesn't return what I've expected.

Comment: can you check the output of `echo` command? does it have newline?

Comment: I think I've found a part of my problem. A component of the `diff` looks saying: `1c1,225
< ` as if one member of the comparison was empty. It seems to be a bug in my script...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output. If I store the two lists as files, and then run `liste_ids_lines=$(cat file1); liste_fichiers=$(cat file2); diff <( echo "$liste_ids_lines" ) <( echo "$liste_fichiers" )` I get an output with only 16 lines, including the `diff` location stuff like `0a1`. Can you show us the script? Does the output change if you use `diff -w`? Also, remember that diff needs sorted files, what is the output of `diff -w <( echo "$liste_ids_lines" | sort ) <( echo "$liste_fichiers" | sort)`?

Comment: Also, why is `a201-extraction_données-et-modélisation_en_objets` not in your desired output? It's only in the `$liste_fichiers`variable.

Comment: Wouldn't `comm` be a better tool for your comparison?

Comment: As an aside, when collecting data into strings you might consider using bash arrays or associative arrays instead. If both lists were associative arrays you could lookup the keys of one to see if it exists as a key in the other, for example.